# Lazy Reading From Sqlite DataBase Using FMDB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi i m using FMDB wrapper to read data from sqlite Database. actually i have different quotes in Database. i have a view which display randomly all the quotes from the Database but which affect the processing speed of the app.i m reading the quotes from the DB and display it in `UIScrollView`  
 i want to read 10 records from the DB eachtime but when i scroll the quotes and reached to quotes/record no 10 then other 10 records should read from the Database how i can do it.  
 `select * from Quotes order by random() limit 10`   
But this just read 10 records from DB i want to read 10 more records when scrolling reached to record no 10. How i can do This Please Help!!!